# Python, how to access unicode variable names in a response

Tags: python, unicode

I have a problem accessing the data I get from a post.

```
r = requests.post(url, data=qs, headers=headers, auth=requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth(acct, apikey))
jr = r.json()
print jr
print jr[reportHeader][numReport]
```

Here is the output;

```
{u'reportHeader': {u'timestamp': 1438371490738L, u'queryParams': {u'ip': [u'59.1
20.54.79']}, u'responseTime': 1824, u'numReport': 3}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ICbulkCSVr.py", line 95, in <module>
    print jr[reportHeader][numReport]
NameError: name 'reportHeader' is not defined
```

What do I need to do to access jr[reportHeader][numReport]?

Comment: Can you post the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to better understand the error message.  It's saying reportHeader is not defined because python is looking for a variable named reportHeader. 
You want:

```
print jr["reportHeader"]["numReport"]
```